# Get an array of objects if one of the field exists in another model in mongoid

Tags: model, mongoid, exists

I am trying to do this:

I have a User model, a Message model

For a certain user, he/she could have a lot of messages (stored in an array).

Now I want to get all the messages the user received, but need to check if the user which sent out the message is still in database.

The process is:

The user has an inbox, which is an array, and stores all the messages other people sent to the user.

The message contains a from_user, which is the id (string) of the sent user. If the user was deleted, the message will remain in the system.

So I want to do a query like this:

Message.find(thisUser.inbox).where(the id of the user exists in the model)

Which means check if the id of the user exists when get records from the message model

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you describe resembles a join. In MongoDB there are two alternatives for that behavior,

- embedding one model to the other
- splitting the query to two separate ones

I think the first option is out of context here.

So the solution I suggest is

```
user = User.find(user_id)
messages = Message.where(user_id: user.id)
```